# How to create a user in keycloak with custom realm role without using role-mapping API?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

when I try to create with a new custom user role, I am able to create the user, but at the role-mapping tab, it is not reflecting:
[image]

payload:

```
{
    "username": "user1",
    "enabled": true,
    "firstName": "user",
    "lastName": "name",
    "credentials": [
        { 
            "type": "password",
            "value": "*******" 
            
        }
    ],
    "realmRoles": [ "user" ],
    "clientRoles": {
         "account": ["view-profile", "manage-account"]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

All roles created in the roles tab should be available as long as they are created in the same realm. By the image you provided it seems you still need to select the user role and click add selected.

Other ways to connect roles to users is utilizing the "Roles" -> "Default roles", or if you are using an external IDP or client scopes, a role mapper in "idp" -> "mappers" for idp and "client scopes" -> "mappers" for scopes.

Comment: "client scopes" -> "mappers" for scopes @Openeye can you explain more about it? I have created a client scope and as of now, I have added a built-in token mapper to view the realm role in the token. Which mapper needs to be used to connect user role for user creation?

Comment: When creating a new client, you can define mappers for that client. It is often useful to save this layout in a client scope to make it easier to create new clients by sharing some common settings. For you, client scopes might be useful for assigning a hardcoded realm role to users, and assign the client scope to users who log in through certain clients. However, if you expand upon your use case I might be able to give you  a better answer.

Comment: use case: create a user and assign a role (admin or user) with {keycloak-server address}auth/admin/realms/ntc/users} with out using keycloak UI.  this seems to be working in the older version. https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/c4e739c5a319cf78a4cff3b87173a84b#gistcomment-2266328

Comment: basically, I want to add a realm role and a client role to the user at a time of creation. For assigning the client scope to users any API available?  or by using a client mapped to the custom client scope will do the job?